# SQL Server Two Column Pivot table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to create a PIVOT TSQL statment that totals the products by date and state/province and provides the AVG Transit Time. Here is what I have so far:

```
select *
from    (select createdate [Date Processed], 
                stateprovince as [Province],
                count(*) as [Total],
                avg(datediff(day,createdate,t.eventdate)) as [AVG Delivery],
                product

            from recipient C left outer join 
            (select delivid, product, eventdesc, eventdate, eventcode
                from deliverystatus 
                where delivid in (select max(deliv_id) 
                                        from deliverystatus 
                                        where eventcode = 'DELIVERED' 
                                        group by product)) as t  ON c.product = t.product
            where account = 3519 and consol <>'' and trknum <> '' and C.createdate between '2/4/2016' and '2/4/2016'
            group by C.createdate, c.stateprovince, c.product
        ) as Q 
pivot   (
            count(product)
            for [Province] in (NY, IL, GA)
        ) as PVT
```

My Result is:

```
Date Processed          Total   AVG Transit NY  IL  GA
2016-02-04 00:00:00.000 1       8           0   0   1
2016-02-04 00:00:00.000 1       11          2   4   1
2016-02-04 00:00:00.000 1       12          0   0   0
2016-02-04 00:00:00.000 1       15          0   0   0
```

I need the result to be:

```
Date Processed          Total   AVG Transit NY  IL  GA
2016-02-04 00:00:00.000 8       11.5        2   4   2
```

The ultimate goal is to have the AVG Transit listed by State/Province like this:

```
Date Processed          Total   Total AVG   NY AVG  IL  AVG   GA AVG
2016-02-04 00:00:00.000 8       11.5        2   8   4   11    2  15
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you just don't group by `c.product`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause after the pivot and either take the `AVG` `SUM` or  `MAX` value for each output column:

```
select [Date Processed], SUM(NY+IL+GA) AS [Total], AVG([AVG Delivery]) AS [AVG Delivery], SUM(NY) AS NY, SUM(IL) AS IL, SUM(GA) AS GA 
from    (select createdate [Date Processed], 
                stateprovince as [Province],
                count(*) as [Total],
                avg(datediff(day,createdate,t.eventdate)) as [AVG Delivery],
                product

            from recipient C left outer join 
            (select delivid, product, eventdesc, eventdate, eventcode
                from deliverystatus 
                where delivid in (select max(deliv_id) 
                                        from deliverystatus 
                                        where eventcode = 'DELIVERED' 
                                        group by product)) as t  ON c.product = t.product
            where account = 3519 and consol <>'' and trknum <> '' and C.createdate between '2/4/2016' and '2/4/2016'
            group by C.createdate, c.stateprovince, c.product
        ) as Q 
pivot   (
            count(product)
            for [Province] in (NY, IL, GA)
        ) as PVT
group by [Date Processed]
```

Comment: That gave me the correct grouping but the count is off. Giving 4 instead of 8

Comment: thanks that got me to the finish line had to make a couple of corrections. To get the correct total I had to Sum all of the States/Province, and I also had to change the MAX to sum on each state. Now everything looks good.